# User authentication and role management asp.net mvc5 using login screen

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I have a asp.net mvc 5 application and I need to display a login screen to the users even though these are internal users. The reason for this some people that are temp workers will not be in AD and the same machine is accessed by many users by using logout, login link. I need to have roles as well. I have a custom database for my application which I would like to use for user and role management. When user logs in, it checks in AD, if not present, then it uses another method to authenticate. Once users log in I need to check what role they belong to and display/hide certain features. What is the best way to achieve this? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Narrow your question down to a specific problem. Nobody here is your worker so nobody is going to build your application for you.

Comment: I am not expecting a complete solution but a suggestion, rather the different approaches that experienced and expert developers use. I have a custom membership provider which I had used in web forms, wanted to know if there is a better way for MVC and anything new in MVC5 which is a improvised solution. I understand no one is obligated to answer, so it is fine if there are no answers